# How to cancel all the thread/ threads in ExcecutorService?

Tags: java

I've written following multi thread program. I want to cancel the all the thread if one of the thread sends back false as return. However though I'm canceling the thread by canceling individual task. Its not working. What changes I need to make inorder to cancel the thread?

I've written following multi thread program. I want to cancel the all the thread if one of the thread sends back false as return. However though I'm canceling the thread by canceling individual task. Its not working. What changes I need to make inorder to cancel the thread?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class BeamWorkerThread implements Callable<Boolean> {


  private List<BeamData> beamData;
  private String threadId;



 public BeamScallopingWorkerThread(
    List<BeamData> beamData, String threadId) {
   super();
   this.beamData = beamData;
   this.threadId = threadId;
  }





 @Override
  public Boolean call() throws Exception {

  Boolean result = true;

  DataValidator validator = new DataValidator();
   Iterator<BeamScallopingData> it = beamData.iterator();

  BeamData data = null;
  while(it.hasNext()){

   data = it.next();

   if(!validator.validateDensity(data.getBin_ll_lat(), data.getBin_ll_lon(), data.getBin_ur_lat(), data.getBin_ur_lon())){
     result = false;
     break;
    }
   }
   return result;
  }

}









   ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        List<Future<Boolean>> results = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();

        long count = 0;
         final long RowLimt = 10000;
         long threadCount = 1;

        while ((beamData = csvReader.read(
           BeamData.class, headers1, processors)) != null) {

         if (count == 0) {
           beamDataList = new ArrayList<BeamData>();
          }

         beamDataList.add(beamData);
          count++;
          if (count == RowLimt) {
           results.add(threadPool
             .submit(new BeamWorkerThread(
               beamDataList, "thread:"
                 + (threadCount++))));
           count = 0;
          }
         }

        results.add(threadPool.submit(new BeamWorkerThread(
           beamDataList, "thread:" + (threadCount++))));
         System.out.println("Number of threads" + threadCount);
         for (Future<Boolean> fs : results)
          try {


           if(fs.get() == false){
            System.out.println("Thread is false");
            for(Future<Boolean> fs1 : results){
             fs1.cancel(true);
            }
           }
          } catch(CancellationException e){

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {

         } catch (ExecutionException e) {

         } finally {
           threadPool.shutdownNow();
          }

       }
```

---

**My comments**

Thanks all for your input I'm overwhelmed by the response. I do know that, well implemented thread takes an app to highs and mean time it a bad implementation brings the app to knees. I agree I'm having fancy idea but I don't have other option. I've a 10 million plus record hence I will have memory constraint and time constraint. I need to tackle both. Hence rather than swallowing whole data I'm breaking it into chunks and also if one data is invalid i don't want to waste time in processing remaining million data. I find @Mark Peters suggestion is an option. Made the changes accordingly I mean added flag to interrupt the task and I'm pretty confused how the future list works. what I understand is that looping through each field of future list starts once all the thread returns its value. In that case, there is no way to cancel all the task in half way from main list. I need to pass on the reference of object to each thread. and if one thread finds invalid data using the thread refernce call the cancel mathod of each thread to set the interrupt flag.

```
while(it.hasNext() && !cancelled) {
         if(!validate){
               // loop through each thread reference and call Cancel method
         }
      }
```

Comment: Why have you put all this irrelevant code in your question? Look at the `ExecutorService` API.

Comment: Looking at Executor Service javadoc, I think you need to use [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

Comment: I've used the shutdownNow method. Still of no use. To validate 1 million record its taking 1.5sec. and when I return false say for 1000sun record. its still takes 1.5sec. I'm expecting it to be less than 500microseconds

Comment: I suggest you think over your design if it is so performance intensive. Don't think in terms of seconds first but try to understand how and when you could interrupt the execution, and how you will do that. Try to implement with the Java facilities and not try to come up with a new fancy idea.

Comment: @SRT_KP I assume you mean 500 milliseconds and not actually 500 microseconds (0.5 milliseconds).

Comment: Yeah 500 milliseconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever attempt you make to cancel all the remaining tasks, it will fail if your code is not carefully written to be *interruptible*. What that exactly entails is beyond just one StackOverflow answer. Some guidelines:

- do not swallow `InterruptedException`. Make its occurrence break the task;
- if your code does not spend much time within interruptible methods, you must insert explicit `Thread.interrupted()` checks and react appropriately.

Writing interruptible code is in general not beginner's stuff, so take care.

Answer (score 2):

Cancelling the `Future` will not interrupt running code.  It primarily serves to prevent the task from being run in the first place.

While you can provide a `true` as a parameter, which will interrupt the thread running the task, that only has an effect if the thread is blocked in code that throws an `InterruptedException`.  Other than that, nothing implicitly checks the `interrupted` status of the thread.

In your case, there is no blocking; it's busy work that is taking time.  One option would be to have a volatile boolean that you check at each stage of your loop:

```
public class BeamWorkerThread implements Callable<Boolean> {

   private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
   @Override
   public Boolean call() throws Exception {
      //...
      while(it.hasNext() && !cancelled) {
         //...
      }
   }

   public void cancel() {
       cancelled = true;
   }
}
```

Then you would keep references to your `BeamWorkerThread` objects and call `cancel()` on it to preempt its execution.

### Why don't I like interrupts?

Marko mentioned that the `cancelled` flag above is essentially reinventing `Thread.interrupted()`.  It's a valid criticism.  Here's why I prefer not to use interrupts in this scenario.

**1. It's dependent on certain threading configurations.**

If your task represents a cancellable piece of code that can be submitted to an executor, or called directly, using `Thread.interrupt()` to cancel execution in the **general case** assumes that the code *receiving* the interrupt will be the code that should know how to cleanly cancel the task.

That might be true in this case, but we only know so because we know how both the cancel and the task work internally.  But imagine we had something like this:

- Task does piece of work
- Listeners are notified on-thread for that first piece of work

  - First listener decides to cancel the task using `Thread.interrupt()`
  - Second listener does some interruptible piece of work, and is interrupted.  It logs but otherwise ignores the interrupt.
- Task does not receive interrupt, and task is not cancelled.

In other words, I feel that `interrupt()` is too *global* of a mechanism.  Like any shared global state, it makes assumptions about all of the actors.  That's what I mean by saying that using `interrupt()` exposes/couples to details about the run context.  By encapsulating it in a `cancel()` method applicable only for that task instance, you eliminate that global state.

**2. It's not always an option.**

The classic example here is an `InputStream`.  If you have a task that blocks on reading from an `InputStream`, `interrupt()` will do nothing to unblock it.  The only way to unblock it is to manually close the stream, and that's something best done in a `cancel()` method for the task itself.  Having one way to cancel a task (e.g. `Cancellable`), regardless of its implementation, seems ideal to me.

Comment: You shouldn't recommend an interruption mechanism other than Java's own, which responds to `cancel(true)`, among many other benefits.

Comment: I agree with @MarkoTopolnik. Interruption is already pretty hard, it's useless to create another implementation. We can see these kind of solutions in tutorials but it's not worth doing. Learn how to do it the Java way and you'll be Ok everywhere.

Comment: @Marko: I disagree.  While interrupt() is a viable option (and you beat me to the punch in suggesting it), using it exposes the run context of the task to the task itself.  Those should be decoupled in my opinion.

Comment: There is no case when you need to implement anything like this. When the Thread is waiting on a monitor, then the InterruptedException is thrown, when it is crunching in a loop, you can check the Thread.interrupted() flag. There is literally no case when you would have to create these kind of tricks.

Comment: @Marko, allprog: Sorry for taking a while, ended up being way too big for a comment.  I've edited my post with some reasons why I don't like reusing `interrupt()` in the general case.  The tl;dr is that it's not always an option (i.e. it depends on what the task is doing) and that it's essentially global state, with all the baggage that comes along with it.

Comment: +1 Good arguments, I admit, but I would still maintain that `interrupt` is the first choice, and only in *quite* complex scenarios it shows weaknesses which you mention. The complexity of the solution should be commensurate with the complexity of the problem it is solving. And yes, it is quite unfortunate that the standard Java I/O is not just blocking-only, but uninterruptible. That's a well-known gripe.

Comment: I find a loophole in your argument where you rely on the second listener being non-compliant with the interruption mechanism: the code which notifies the listeners is under your control and can clearly handle the interrupt.

Comment: @Marko: It's definitely the simpler option here (and definitely worthy of +1 and being the correct answer), but to me, the pernicious nature of global state is that a seemingly harmless refactoring of the task down the road could cause bugs that are hard to reproduce.  I find it easier as a rule to stay away from global state.

Comment: @Marko: In that example I meant that the second listener, whose implementation might not be known to the author of the task (as listeners are usually pluggable) could receive the interrupt and either opt to ignore it (probably a bug) or not propagate it in the way expected by the task.

Comment: Yes, but you say the first listener raises the interrupt. Then control returns to the main listener-notifying loop, which gets the chance to abort. Other than that, the argument about alien code is absolutely valid (a while ago I even wrote an answer with just that point).

Comment: @Marko: Ah, good point, and I assume that's similar to what an `Executor` would do if it wants to reuse a thread: after all, you could have an equivalent scenario where you cancel a task interruptibly, but the task doesn't clear the interrupted status.  You certainly wouldn't want the next task to use that thread to be immediately interrupted just because it was unlucky.  But add another level of indirection and the scenario still stands :-).

Comment: @MarkPeters can you please validate my view please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` method. It will stop the executor from accepting more submissions and returns with the `Future` objects of the ongoing tasks that you can call `cancel(true)` on to interrupt the execution. Of course, you will have to discard this executor as it cannot be restarted.

The `cancel()` method may not terminate the execution immediately if the Thread is not waiting on a *monitor* (not blocked interruptibly), and also if you swallow the InterruptedException that will be raised in this case.